# Loading image and pdf by sqlldr not working

Tags: blob, apex

I am trying to load image and pdf files in to a table using sqlldr. Loading pdf works great, loading images perhaps work  as well according to sqlldr log however I can not see the images through Apex. Yes, I know how to get images visible in apex. Here is my table structure,

```
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
IMAGE_PDF_ID    NUMBER  No  -   1
IMAGE_NAME  VARCHAR2(3000)  Yes -   -
IMAGE_FILE  BLOB    Yes -   -
PDF_NAME    VARCHAR2(3000)  Yes -   -
PDF_FILE    BLOB    Yes -   -
MIMETYPE    VARCHAR2(300)   Yes -   -
LAST_UPDATED    TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE Yes -   -
PUBLICATION_NO  VARCHAR2(30)    Yes -   -
```

Here is my control file.

```
OPTIONS (skip=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE testload.txt
INTO TABLE SUMAN.IMAGE_AND_PDF
REPLACE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
PUBLICATION_NO,
IMAGE_NAME,
PDF_NAME,
IMAGE_FILE LOBFILE(IMAGE_NAME),
PDF_FILE LOBFILE(PDF_NAME)
TERMINATED BY EOF
 )
```

And finally, this is the structure of my infile testload.txt

```
PUBLICATION_NO,IMAGE_NAME,PDF_NAME
WO2011067192,WO2011067192.JPG,WO2011067192.pdf
WO2011026886,WO2011026886.JPG,WO2011026886.pdf
US20120168731,US20120168731.JPG,US20120168731.pdf 
WO2010079051,WO2010079051.JPG,WO2010079051.pdf
```

After upload, table looks well populated,

see image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Q3i.jpg

However, they do not show up in Apex pages.So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think I figure it out. Looks like the last command in control file actually triggers the upload. When I moved IMAGE_FILE LOBFILE(IMAGE_FILE) at the end of the control file, images were loaded successfully.

Comment: Figured out the problem completely. Yes, off-course I can load multiple BLOB at the same time via sqlldr. All I have to is add TERMINATED BY EOF at the end of PDF_FILE and IMAGE_FILE rows.